# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module -- jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, jspdf

I have been trying to create a html and javascript application that uses the jspdf module to export pdf files.

Everytime i run the code bellow I get the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js">
            
        </script>
            
        <script type="text/javascript">
            import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
    
            // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
            const doc = new jsPDF();
    
            doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
            doc.save("a4.pdf");
            alert("hello")
        </script>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

See "Other Module Formats" > "Globals" in the [NPM Package Page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf).

You can't use `import` statement outside an [ES6 module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Generally the script tag has `type` attribute set to `module`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js">
            
        </script>
            
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
            const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
            
            const doc = new jsPDF();
    
            doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
            doc.save("a4.pdf");
            alert("hello")
        </script>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That works, thankyou, im still very new to JavaScript.

Comment: @Ernsto Stifano, Works for me as well, Thank you!